# AAPT2 Compile time error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-resources, aapt2

I've been using Android Studio perfectly well for a long time now but when I tried using `CardView` in my layout file.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
/Users/professori/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/cardview-v7-25.0.0.aar/1cf3ea204bf2d379f4a71d608f48a715/res/values/values.xml
Error:(18, 5) error: expected color reference but got (raw string) #000t.
/Users/professori/Projects/house/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
Error:(2146) expected color reference but got (raw string) #000t.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 19s
Information:7 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I am using `buildToolsVersion 27.0.1` and `v26.1.0` of the respective support libraries. My `gradle` version is 3.0.1.

I have tried cleaning the project multiple times and even restarting Android Studio but it hasn't helped. Some StackOverflow answers suggest disabling aapt2 in `gradle.properties` but that just brings some more problems I'd rather not get into.

Is there a permanent way of getting rid of this problem? It's now happened twice in 2 separate projects I'm working on.

Comment: It looks like this library is trying to use "#000t" as a color, but it's not a valid code. You can look at the XML file (/Users/professori/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/cardview-v7-25.0.0.aar/1cf3ea204bf2d379f4a71d608f48a715/res/values/values.xml), find which resource is using the incorrect color and override it in your own app to fix this error.

Comment: any update about which resource was using the invalid color?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the color code You are using  "#000t" 
**use a correct color code** after rebuild it, this will work if not then try below solutions

1:- remove all unnecessary XML files from your code

2:- Reopen and Check XML files

**clean and Rebuild Project**

If there is Still Problem

Go to your gradle.properties write the below code

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

and then Go to your build.gradle(app) write the below code and Sync your project

```
aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
```

[image: Like this Image]

**Note android.enableAapt2=false is deprecated, and will be removed by the end of 2018, so this doesn't solve the problem, is just a temporary workaround**